# How do I read an attribute on a class at runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, custom-attributes

I am trying to create a generic method that will read an attribute on a class and return that value at runtime. How do would I do this?

**Note: DomainName attribute is of class DomainNameAttribute.**

```
[DomainName("MyTable")]
Public class MyClass : DomainBase
{}
```

What I am trying to generate:

```
//This should return "MyTable"
String DomainNameValue = GetDomainName<MyClass>();
```

Comment: Official microsoft link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct.aspx

Comment: Important corollary question how to get all types in assembly with custom attribute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 286, accepted):

```
public string GetDomainName<T>()
{
    var dnAttribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DomainNameAttribute), true
    ).FirstOrDefault() as DomainNameAttribute;
    if (dnAttribute != null)
    {
        return dnAttribute.Name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

This method could be further generalized to work with any attribute:

```
public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetAttributeValue<TAttribute, TValue>(
        this Type type, 
        Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector) 
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var att = type.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(TAttribute), true
        ).FirstOrDefault() as TAttribute;
        if (att != null)
        {
            return valueSelector(att);
        }
        return default(TValue);
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
string name = typeof(MyClass)
    .GetAttributeValue((DomainNameAttribute dna) => dna.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your diligence in answering the question!

Comment: This extension method could be further generalized by extending MemberInfo, a base class of Type and all - or at least *most* - of a Type's members. Doing so would open this up to allow reading attributes from Properties, Fields, and even Events.

Comment: Overly complicated.  There's no need to use lambda to select the attribute value.  If you enough to write the lambda, you know enough to just access the field.

Comment: How can i extend this approach this to get `const Filed` in static class?

Answer (score 66):

There is already an extension to do this.

```
namespace System.Reflection
{
    // Summary:
    //     Contains static methods for retrieving custom attributes.
    public static class CustomAttributeExtensions
    {
        public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this MemberInfo element, bool inherit) where T : Attribute;
    }
}
```

So:

```
var attr = typeof(MyClass).GetCustomAttribute<DomainNameAttribute>(false);
return attr != null ? attr.DomainName : "";
```

Comment: True. But only .NET 4.5 and newer. I'm still developing library code where I can't use this method :(

Answer (score 16):

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(MyClass);
object[] attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);

for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Length; i++)
{
    if (attributes[i] is DomainNameAttribute)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(((DomainNameAttribute) attributes[i]).Name);
    }   
}
```

Comment: And +1 for not using "var", so it's easy to understand how it works.

Comment: It doesnt compile. But "System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo();" do

Answer (score 7):

I used Darin Dimitrov's answer to create a generic extension to get member attributes for any member in a class (instead of attributes for a class). I'm posting it here because others may find it useful:

```
public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the value of a member attribute for any member in a class.
    ///     (a member is a Field, Property, Method, etc...)    
    /// <remarks>
    /// If there is more than one member of the same name in the class, it will return the first one (this applies to overloaded methods)
    /// </remarks>
    /// <example>
    /// Read System.ComponentModel Description Attribute from method 'MyMethodName' in class 'MyClass': 
    ///     var Attribute = typeof(MyClass).GetAttribute("MyMethodName", (DescriptionAttribute d) => d.Description);
    /// </example>
    /// <param name="type">The class that contains the member as a type</param>
    /// <param name="MemberName">Name of the member in the class</param>
    /// <param name="valueSelector">Attribute type and property to get (will return first instance if there are multiple attributes of the same type)</param>
    /// <param name="inherit">true to search this member's inheritance chain to find the attributes; otherwise, false. This parameter is ignored for properties and events</param>
    /// </summary>    
    public static TValue GetAttribute<TAttribute, TValue>(this Type type, string MemberName, Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector, bool inherit = false) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var att = type.GetMember(MemberName).FirstOrDefault().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), inherit).FirstOrDefault() as TAttribute;
        if (att != null)
        {
            return valueSelector(att);
        }
        return default(TValue);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
//Read System.ComponentModel Description Attribute from method 'MyMethodName' in class 'MyClass'
var Attribute = typeof(MyClass).GetAttribute("MyMethodName", (DescriptionAttribute d) => d.Description);
```

Comment: Inheritance doesn't work on derived properties - for that, you'll need to call a separate static method (System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes) http://stackoverflow.com/a/7175762/184910

Answer (score 3):

A simplified version of Darin Dimitrov's first solution:

```
public string GetDomainName<T>()
{
    var dnAttribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<DomainNameAttribute>(true);
    if (dnAttribute != null)
    {
        return dnAttribute.Name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
' Simplified Generic version. 
Shared Function GetAttribute(Of TAttribute)(info As MemberInfo) As TAttribute
    Return info.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(TAttribute), _
                                    False).FirstOrDefault()
End Function

' Example usage over PropertyInfo
Dim fieldAttr = GetAttribute(Of DataObjectFieldAttribute)(pInfo)
If fieldAttr IsNot Nothing AndAlso fieldAttr.PrimaryKey Then
    keys.Add(pInfo.Name)
End If
```

Probably just as easy to use the body of generic function inline.
It doesn't make any sense to me to make the function generic over the type MyClass.

```
string DomainName = GetAttribute<DomainNameAttribute>(typeof(MyClass)).Name
// null reference exception if MyClass doesn't have the attribute.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs a nullable result and for this to work across Enums, PropertyInfo and classes, here's how I solved it.  This is a modification of Darin Dimitrov's updated solution.

```
public static object GetAttributeValue<TAttribute, TValue>(this object val, Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector) where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    try
    {
        Type t = val.GetType();
        TAttribute attr;
        if (t.IsEnum && t.GetField(val.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() is TAttribute att)
        {
            // Applies to Enum values
            attr = att;
        }
        else if (val is PropertyInfo pi && pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() is TAttribute piAtt)
        {
            // Applies to Properties in a Class
            attr = piAtt;
        }
        else
        {
            // Applies to classes
            attr = (TAttribute)t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return valueSelector(attr);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
// Class
SettingsEnum.SettingGroup settingGroup = (SettingsEnum.SettingGroup)(this.GetAttributeValue((SettingGroupAttribute attr) => attr.Value) as SettingsEnum.SettingGroup?);

// Enum
DescriptionAttribute desc = settingGroup.GetAttributeValue((DescriptionAttribute attr) => attr) as DescriptionAttribute;

// PropertyInfo       
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    string setting = ((SettingsEnum.SettingName)(pi.GetAttributeValue((SettingNameAttribute attr) => attr.Value) as SettingsEnum.SettingName?)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you have Overridden Methods with same Name Use the helper below

```
public static TValue GetControllerMethodAttributeValue<T, TT, TAttribute, TValue>(this T type, Expression<Func<T, TT>> exp, Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector) where TAttribute : Attribute
        {
            var memberExpression = exp?.Body as MethodCallExpression;

            if (memberExpression.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() is TAttribute attr && valueSelector != null)
            {
                return valueSelector(attr);
            }

            return default(TValue);
        }
```

> Usage: var someController = new SomeController(Some params); var str =
>   typeof(SomeController).GetControllerMethodAttributeValue(x =>
>   someController.SomeMethod(It.IsAny()), (RouteAttribute
>   routeAttribute) => routeAttribute.Template);

Answer (score -1):

Rather then write a lot of code, just do this:

```
{         
   dynamic tableNameAttribute = typeof(T).CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
   dynamic tableName = tableNameAttribute.Substring(tableNameAttribute.LastIndexOf('.'), tableNameAttribute.LastIndexOf('\\'));    
}
```