# getting tag names using postsharp in c# .net

Tags: c#, postsharp

i am using the following code as

```
 [DisplayOrder]  
public static void ss()
{
    Console.WriteLine("ss");

 }
```

i am using following code for getting method name as

```
 foreach (MethodInfo targetMethod in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.SuppressChangeType | BindingFlags.ExactBinding | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.GetProperty ))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("=== " + targetMethod.Name);


                {
                    instances.Add(new AspectInstance(targetMethod, aspectToApply));
                }

            }
            foreach (Type nestedType in type.GetNestedTypes())
            {
                ProcessType(nestedType, instances);
            }
        }
```

the name of method comes and executes well

i do not know how to get the tag name as "   [DisplayOrder]   " .

got stuck here

do not know how to proceed

Comment: You're asking "How do I read the attributes at runtime"?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 2):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw(v=vs.80).aspx