# How can I extract a list of Tests from an MsTest assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, mstest

I have an assembly that I have created from a suite of SpecFlow MsTests.

What I am looking to do is to run a bit of code over the assembly DLL in order to extract a list of the test names from the contained test classes.

I assume it will require reading the attributes via Reflection or something similar, im just not sure where to start.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward:

Use reflection to load the assembly, iterate over all public classes and for each class, check if the `TestClass` attribute is set.

Then for each class, iterate over each public method and check if the `TestMethod` attribute is set.

As result you could for eaxmaple use a combination of class and method names.

Comment: Ah I see so they will have those specific attributes, that makes sense. I shall give that a shot thanks.