# Force a class to implement an enum with no value constrain

Tags: c#, class, enums, interface

I've different classes (e.g.: Player, Enemy, Asteroids...) - that are supposed to have one of different statuses (e.g.: ok, teleporting...).

```
enum Status
{
    Ok,
    Teleporting,
    ...
};
```

**Using an interface**, I'd like to force those classes to declare **only the existance** of a enum status variable inside them. However, I want **no constraints on values**. That is, a Player and an Enemy can have different values inside status (e.g.: one can teleport, the other one can't).

How can I do that?

## Update1

```
public enum Status
{
    Ok,
    Teleporting
};

public interface IHaveStatus
{
    Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

## Update 2

```
public enum Status
{
    Ok,
    Teleporting
};

public interface IHaveStatus
{
    Status status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the interface as follows:

```
public interface IHaveStatus {
    Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

and let the specific classes implement that interface:

```
class Player: IHaveStatus {
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

This will not limit the usage of the status field, it can have any value that is legal for the `Status` enum.

If (however) you would like to apply some logic (enemy can't teleport), than this may not be the right design.

If you want to specify that players have certain capabillities (i.e.: teleporting) you could use an attribute or an interface to identify those classes.

**Using interfaces:**

```
public interface ICanTeleport { }

public class Player : ICanTeleport { ... }
```

you can determine capabillities using a cast:

```
if(somePlayer is ICanTeleport) { .. }
```

**or when using [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes):**

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]  
public class Teleporter : System.Attribute  
{ }

[Teleporter()]
public class Player { ... }
```

Then you will have to use reflection to determine the attributes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime).

- Using interfaces makes the behavior bound to the class inheritance. It also gives you the abillity to add methods to the interface (i.e. a `Teleport(coordinates)` method).
- Using attributes gives more possibillites to mix and match capabillities on the fly, as there is no class hierarchy forcing the capabillities.

Comment: I'm not sure I would force a setter on the interface, but other then that, great answer! :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled hey, it's just a property. do with it what you want -)

Comment: It's just that both our answers was the same other then that detail when I wrote that comment...

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Thanks for the in-depth answer. So in the end the code will be like this:

(See updated post: #Update1)

And classes that implements the IHaveStatus interface will only be able to use **all or some** of the values exposed in `public enum Status` (in this case: ok and teleporting), but not add new one? Is this correct?

By the way, while we discuss, I'll review my design choices :)

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ and why can't I write #Update2 ?

Comment: @Giovarco if you extend the enum (add new values), all classes that implemented the interface / enum will directly be able to use these new values (ignoring technicallities such as compile times of diffrent assemblies etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, a simple interface like this will do it:

```
 public interface IHaveStatus
 {
      Status Status {get;}
 }
```

Values constraints I would put in the concrete classes. For instance, if a player can't teleport, a good place to constraint that would be in the property setter:

```
public class Player : IHaveStatus
{
    private Status _status;

    public Status Status 
    {
        get {return _status;}
        set
        {
            // a player can't teleport...
            if(value != Status.Teleport)
            {
                _status = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not with the same enum type. You would have to declare different enums for every set of allowed values. Pro: you get compile time checking (as long as you explicitly assign values as is usually the case with Enums values). Con: You have to declare a new Enum for every allowable range.

Alternatively you check the incoming value at run time at the type level in the `setter` (method or property) and enforce any constraint there. Pro: you only need one enum for the complete range. Con: The downside of this solution is you could have bugs that you will not catch until runtime.

#### Solution enum per accepted range

```
enum EnemyStatus
{
    Ok
}

enum UserStatus
{
    Ok,
    Teleporting
}
```

#### Solution constraint at the type level

```
class Enemy : IStatusable {

  public Status CurrentStatus {
    get {return _status;}
    set {if(value == Status.Teleporting) throw new NotSupportedException();
         this._status = value;
    }}
}

interface IStatusable {
   Status CurrentStatus {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The question was specifically about NOT limiting the possible values. I think you may have misread the question..

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to combine multiple values in a single enum field if enum is marked with `[Flags]` attribute:

```
[Flags]
enum Status
{
    Ok = 0,
    Teleporting = 1,
    Flying = 2,
    Dancing = 4
}
```

then declare interface with one enum property:

```
interface Base
{
    Status Abilities { get; }
}

class Player : Base
{
    public Status Abilities { get; set; }
}
```

and test objects for different values like this:

```
var p = new Player();
p.Abilities = Status.Ok | Status.Teleporting;

bool canTeleport = p.Abilities.HasFlag(Status.Teleporting);
bool canFly = p.Abilities.HasFlag(Status.Flying);
```