# Understanding the use of 'Attributes'

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-attributes

I'm trying to understand the use of `Attributes` *a bit better*.
I understand that:

- How to access `Attributes` in my code [using reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/accessing-attributes-by-using-reflection).
- How to create [custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes)
- How to specify explicitly an [attribute target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-targets)

Now I wants to do some more with attributes and curious about:

- How predefined attributes (e.g. `DllImportAttribute` or `STAThread`) perform there functionalities? Because we just use these attributes and respective functionalities are performed. e.g. With the help of `DllImportAttribute`, I just declare that my method `abc()` needs `xyz.dll` and respective DLL is loaded. I didn't write code to search and load the DLL `xyz.dll`.
- Dose *.NET Runtime Environment* or Compilers provide **special treatment** to predefined attributes? Here by *special treatment* I meant that, dose *.NET Runtime Environment* or Compilers detects that there is some predefined attributes used in code and runs respective method?
- If so then, how can I provide/add such information with .NET Runtime Environment or Compilers (even if only at my local PC) so that it runs a special method whenever my user defined attribute is used in any of the project?

Comment: I don't know java and I have no clue what is your problem with attributes. Sounds a *bit* broad to me, rather ask 2 questions.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use attributes to specify certain code to run before/after/on condition upon running method, right? Google for *code contract c#*.

Comment: @Sinatr Ok, I have created a separate question for [Annotations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277637/understanding-the-use-of-annotations). I'll update this question for C#(code and question clarity), as on this question we are in discussion on the response of @MichaelRandall for `Attributes` in C#.NET.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I want to understand that how I can create my custom attribute so that .NET Runtime notify me whenever my custom attribute is used in code. I have updated my question for more clarity.

Comment: The non-intuitive requirement is that there must be *some* code that uses Reflection to find the attribute back.  That code is often very well hidden.  Like [DllImport], built into the jitter.  [STAThread], built in the CLR.  Also, say, [Browsable], built into the PropertyGrid control, [AssemblyVersion], built into the C# compiler.  This kind of reflection code is not extensible by mere mortals.  So "run a special method" is not really in the cards.  You could consider an IL rewriter, PostSharp is a product that does this.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for this information. May you provide the link for this information?

Comment: https://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: @HansPassant I meant by _That code is often very well hidden. Like [DllImport], built into the jitter. [STAThread], built in the CLR. Also, say, [Browsable], built into the PropertyGrid control, [AssemblyVersion], built into the C# compiler._

Answer (score 0):

There is no mystery really...

An attribute is actually an object that is associated with any of these elements: `Assembly`, `Class`, `Method`, `Delegate`, `Enum`, `Event`, `Field`, `Interface`, `Property` and `Struct`.

They can be used to associate declarative information and retrieve such information (at *Runtime*) by using reflection. In other words, you can use attributes to inject additional information to the assemblies that can be queried at *Runtime* if needed using reflection.

An attribute basically just comprises of its name and optionally, a list of parameters.

From MSDN [Attributes (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/)

> Attributes provide a powerful method of associating metadata, or
>   declarative information, with code (assemblies, types, methods,
>   properties, and so forth). After an attribute is associated with a
>   program entity, the attribute can be queried at run time by using a
>   technique called reflection. For more information, see Reflection
>   (C#).
>
> **Attributes have the following properties**:
>
> - Attributes add metadata to your program. Metadata is information about the types defined in a program. All .NET assemblies contain a
>     specified set of metadata that describes the types and type members
>     defined in the assembly. You can add custom attributes to specify any
>     additional information that is required. For more information, see,
>     Creating Custom Attributes (C#).
> - You can apply one or more attributes to entire assemblies, modules, or smaller program elements such as classes and properties.
> - Attributes can accept arguments in the same way as methods and properties.
>
> Your program can examine its own metadata or the metadata in other
>   programs by using reflection. For more information, see Accessing
>   Attributes by Using Reflection (C#).

If you want to receive information about the Metadata stored in an Attribute you need to do something like this

**Exmaple**

Lifted from [How do I read an attribute on a class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime)

```
[DomainName("MyTable")]
Public class MyClass : DomainBase
{}

...

public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetAttributeValue<TAttribute, TValue>(
        this Type type, 
        Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector) 
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var att = type.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(TAttribute), true
        ).FirstOrDefault() as TAttribute;
        if (att != null)
        {
            return valueSelector(att);
        }
        return default(TValue);
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
string name = typeof(MyClass).GetAttributeValue((DomainNameAttribute dna) => dna.Name);
```

Comment: I wonder _how some attributes are handled mysteriously_  ? e.g. `DllImportAttribute` or `STAThread`. Does .NET compilers having special supports for _such, predefined attributes_? If yes then _Is there any mechanism so that we can add such support for user defined attributes?_

Comment: I understand that I can use Reflections, _if I have to_ use then _explicitely_. But _when these Reflections_ are called for Attributes like `DllImportAttribute` or `STAThread`? And who calls it? .NET compilers, .NET Run-time Envirenment or something else?

Comment: @cse Yeah the framework, deep down somewhere. you can actually search the Microsoft source for framework code.

Comment: Yeah there are more qualified people to say, however it is just used like everyone else can use attributes. and i doubt would be a special case. that is my guess

Comment: *"But when these Reflections are called for Attributes like DllImportAttribute or STAThread"* - those are used by .net infrastructure, you don't care when they are called, you only care to specify those to achieve certain things.

Comment: @Sinatr My intention is to _do something behind the scene_ as in case of `DllImportAttribute` or `STAThread`. I just wants to understand that .NET provides _special privileges_ to inbuilt annotations or we can also _do something like this_ with user defined Annotations?

Comment: There is no behind the scenes with attributes, its all just runtime metadata.

Comment: @MichaelRandall As provided in your example, it is known in advance that _which class is using the custom attribute?_ But I don't know in advance that which other classes are using my custom attribute. Moreover, it can be case that some other user defined his class in future and using the _custom attribute_.