# Get [Authorize] data from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-webapi, authorize

I have code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdministrators")]
public class ButtonStyleController : ControllerBase
{
```

in other place:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdministrators,CompanyAdministrators")]
public class BankController : ControllerBase
{
```

and even:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "CompanyAdministrators")]
public class DriverController : ApiControllerBase
{
```

I need to check which roles are allowed for current controller in code. Is it possible?

Comment: You do it the same way you read any attribute on a class. See here: [How do I read an attribute on a class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get an attribute, of type `AuthorizeAttribute`, from a class then access the Roles property.

```
AuthorizeAttribute currentAuthorizeAttribute = (AuthorizeAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DriverController), typeof(AuthorizeAttribute));
string roles = currentAuthorizeAttribute.Roles;
```