# Can you link to a Razor component without hard-coding its URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to create a github pages website with the new Blazor WASM. I use C# almost every day for work, but I've never used Blazor/Razor/ASP.NET before, so it's very possible that I'm trying to use server-side techniques that won't work here.

I have a group of pages, and I want to show a little preview of each page with a link to that page on the homepage. All of these pages implement the same component base class. For example, *Sample.razor* might look like

```
@page "/sample"
@inherits GroupBase

<!-- html here -->
@code {
    public override string Name { get; } = "Sample";
}
```

*Index.razor* might look like

```
@page "/"

@foreach (GroupBase p in mPagesToPreview)
    {
        <a href="   ">@p.Name</a>
    }
@code {
    List<GroupBase> mPagesToPreview = new List<GroupBase> { new Sample() };
}
```

Is there any way to route to the *Sample* page without explicitly putting in "/sample"? Or even using a normal link (I've checked both *a* and *NavLink*) with a function similar to *nameOf()* or *getType()*?

My best option right now is to add a *URL* property to the base, but it seems like I shouldn't have to type out "/sample" twice. (It's not hard; it's the principle of the thing!)

I've also seen some examples of people injecting a *NavigationManager* and then using that to deduce the URL, but that would also have to be  repeated for each page. I've seen some examples that get the page directive from *RouteData.Values*, but those were Razor pages. I couldn't figure out how to create a *RouteData* object or use it as a static class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class RouteAttribute to find the route.
It looks like this:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/counter")]
public partial class Counter : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
```

See [How do I read an attribute on a class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime)