# Model Display Name in Data-Grid as Column

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I would like to publish some information in a two-dimension data-grid. First column the name of the attribute, second the current value. Currently I created an array that I attached to the WPF data-grid and filled it upside down with an Attribute = "Username" and a Value = "Waldow". Now I would like to know if there is maybe another way by using a model class where I define every attribute as a string but in the end can display it in the same way, but have a better code.
Let`s say this is my model:

```
public class InformationModel
{
    [Description("Hostname_Description")]
    [Display(Name = "Hostname_Display")]
    public string Hostname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username_Display")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

...... more values
        
    }
```

Now I want a Datagrid like this:

```
Hostname | PC0004
Username | Waldow
```

but by just specifying the value:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_information" ItemsSource="{Binding Information}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="11,10,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Single" AlternationCount="1">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Display}" Header="Attribute"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Value"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

The model class will not be extended, meaning the entries will always be the same and no more rows will be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should transform your model into a view model that contains a property per column that you want to display in the `DataGrid` (and bind to an `IEnumerable<InformationViewModel>`):

```
public class InformationModel
{
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

You can then set the properties based on the attributes [using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime).

There is no way to retrieve the value of the attributes in XAML though. You can only bind to public properties. It's then up to you as a developer to set these properties.

You might set the `Attribute` property of the sample class above to the string "Hostname", or to the value of the attribute that you can get [using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime). How the value is set doesn't matter as far as the XAML/UI is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I used an own class. So basically in my main class I set a listener on my informationModel and always when a value got changed it will launch the method Model_PropertyChanged. My InformationModel got extended by INotifyPropertyChanged, which calls OnPropertyChanged always when a value got changed:

```
public MainViewModel() {
// set listener
            informationmodel.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
}

        private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property changed: " + e.PropertyName);
            // Update object in list
            var obj = Informationdgm.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute == informationmodel.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.Name.ToString());
            if (obj != null)
            {
                obj.Value = informationmodel.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetValue(informationmodel, null);

            }

        }
```