# DbContext.OnModelCreating - Reading custom attribute for each DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, data-annotations, dbset

I have a `IdSeqAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class IdSeq(string seq) : Attribute
{
    public string Seq = seq;
}
```

and use it like this (about 60 classes):

```
[IdSeq("Customer")]
public class Customer : MyModel
{
    public string Nome { get; set; } = "";
}

[IdSeq("Product")]
public class Product : MyModel
{
    public string Nome { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Then, I need to get this attibute on DbContext.OnModelCreating, for each DbSet<>:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var annotatios = entityType.GetAnnotations();
            // here, I can see two attributes, but "IdSeq" isn't one of them.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read an attribute on a class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656189/how-do-i-read-an-attribute-on-a-class-at-runtime)

Comment: `entityType.ClrType` is your class type. Get attributes using standard technique. `GetAnnotations()` is not proper way, it is more EF Core API specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`IReadOnlyTypeBase.ClrType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ireadonlytypebase.clrtype?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-ireadonlytypebase-clrtype) property to get the entity type and get custom attributes from it:

```
var idSeq = entityType.ClrType.GetCustomAttribute<IdSeq>()
```