# Inherited attributes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, attributes

**Attribute code**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
class IgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

**Base class**

```
abstract class ManagementUnit
{
    [Ignore]
    public abstract byte UnitType { get; }
}
```

**Main class**

```
class Region : ManagementUnit
{
    public override byte UnitType
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        Type t = typeof(Region);
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties())
        {
            if (p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IgnoreAttribute), true).Length != 0)
                Console.WriteLine("have attr");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("don't have attr");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:** `don't have attr`

Explain why this is happening? After all, it must inherited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The inherited flag dictates whether the attribute can be inherited.
>   The default for this value is false. However, if the inherited flag is
>   set to true, its meaning depends on the value of the AllowMultiple
>   flag. If the inherited flag is set to true and the AllowMultiple flag
>   is false, the attribute will override the inherited attribute.
>   However, if the inherited flag is set to true and the AllowMultiple
>   flag is also set to true, the attribute accumulates on the member.

from http://aclacl.brinkster.net/InsideC/32ch09f.htm
Check the chapter Specifying Inheritance Attribute Rules

EDIT: check [Inheritance of Custom Attributes on Abstract Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520035/inheritance-of-custom-attributes-on-abstract-properties)
The first answer:

> It's the GetCustomAttributes() method that does not look at parent
>   declarations. It only looks at attributes applied to the specified
>   member.

Comment: No, the default for "inherited" is true.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The **inheritance flag in PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes is ignored for both properties and events** as documented by: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx . But you can use one of the Attribute.GetCustomAttributes overloads to enable inheritance of properties (or events).

This issue is discussed in more details in: http://blog.seancarpenter.net/2012/12/15/getcustomattributes-and-overridden-properties/