# How to get attributes from a property if I don't know if they are in the interface or concrete class?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following code:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    [DisplayName("test")]
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using reflection I need to get the attribute from the property `Name`. However I don't know if the `Type` I will receive is an interface or the concrete class.

If I try to do a `prop.GetCustomAttributes(true)` on the concrete class it doesn't return the attribute I've set on the interface. I would like it to return in this case.

Is there a method to get attributes defined on the concrete class and the interface as well? Or how could I handle this?

Comment: Check [attribute inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240960/how-does-inheritance-work-for-attributes) and how they are [handled on the property level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520035/inheritance-of-custom-attributes-on-abstract-properties).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in method to do this, but you can write one:

```
public static T GetAttribute<T>(this PropertyInfo pi) where T : Attribute
{
    var attr = pi.GetCustomAttribute<T>();
    if (attr != null) return attr;

    var type = pi.DeclaringType;
    var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

    foreach(var i in interfaces)
    {
        var p = i.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x,typeof(T)));           
        if (p != null)
            return p.GetCustomAttribute<T>();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var f = new Foo();
var prop = f.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
var attr = prop.GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The class [doesn't inherit the attributes from the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540749/can-a-c-sharp-class-inherit-attributes-from-its-interface). So you'll have to call `Type.GetInterfaces()` to find out the interfaces, and try to find the attributes on that.