# Attribute.IsDefined vs MemberInfo.IsDefined - difference of the inherited parameter

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, properties, attributes

My question deals with the check of inherited attributes of properties.

Like described in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520035/inheritance-of-custom-attributes-on-abstract-properties) the methods [Attribute.IsDefined(MemberInfo, Type, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) **(1)** and [MemberInfo.IsDefined(Type, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) **(2)** are basically the same. Both are checking if an attribute is used. But there is a serious difference at the inherit parameter if I want to check a property:

**(1):**

> If true, specifies to also search the ancestors of element for custom attributes.

**(2):**

> true to search this member's inheritance chain to find the attributes; otherwise, false.**This parameter is ignored for properties and events**; see Remarks.

*(The remarks only recommend the usage of **(1)**)*

It´s no problem to use **(1)** to get a inherited attribute of a property. But my question is the **why**: Why is this feature implemented like this? What is the reason, the usage or the benefit? From my point, there is a method who ignores a parameter and thats not really a clean solution.

Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 5):

My guess (and it *is* no more a guess) - the reason is backwards compatibility.

`PropertyInfo.IsDefined` and `EventInfo.IsDefined` ignored the `inherit` parameter since they were introduced in .NET 1.0. The static methods on `Attribute` were introduced in .NET 2.0, and were amended to support inheritance of properties and events. If they were to change that behavior, old code that has set `inherit` to true could start getting unexpected attributes.

Just one of many inconsistencies in the BCL... :)